# Dataframe cannot support any missing labels in terms of query result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get query result in terms of items defined in list.

I already got a query result shown below.

Here is my query result

```
df.query("type == 'TV'")["letter"].value_counts()

T    39
E    32
Q    14
M     6
C     3
Y     1
G     1
```

Here is my code snippet shown below

```
letter_order =  ['G', 'T', 'A', 'E', 'Y', 'U', 'C', 'I', 'O', 'W', 'Q', 'M']
tv_rating = df.query("type == 'TV'")["letter"].value_counts()[letter_order].fillna(0)
```

I want to get a result as shown below but there is an error here.

```
T    39
E    32
Q    14
M     6
C     3
Y     1
G     1
U     0
A     0
```

...   ...

The `error` is shown below

```
KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Use `df.query("type == 'TV'")["letter"].value_counts(dropna=False).fillna(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
df.query("type == 'TV'")["letter"].value_counts().reindex(letter_order).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `reindex`

```
df.query("type == 'TV'")["letter"].value_counts().reindex(letter_order).fillna(0)
```